# I am unable to install a package on V11.3, which previously worked on V6.0

Tags: packages

It is BUtools (both old and new version) http://webspn.hit.bme.hu/~telek/tools/butools/

I moved the files from Downloads to AddOns inserted the path using insert file

```
dir = "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram 
Research\\Mathematica\\11.3\\AddOns\
\\BuTools2\\PH.m";
AppendTo[$Path, dir];
<< "BuTools2`PH`"
<< PH.m
```

tried also file install, but I'm missing something which changed from  Mathematica 6

Answer (score 8):

- Download the zip file and extract it. You will find a directory named `BuTools` in `butool2/Mathematica`.
- Evaluate `SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]` to open the correct location where packages should be installed.
- Move the `BuTools` directory to this location.
- Now you can load the package using the command `` <<BuTools` ``. *Nothing else needs to be done.*

Please contact the authors of the package and ask them to provide clear installation instructions.

Also, you should never modify the installation directory of Mathematica. Never change anything in the directory `C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram 
Research\\Mathematica`

Comment: Thanks, it works!